# Can OHLC plots have up/down colour fills like Candle Stick increase/ decrease fills?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am using Core-Plot to draw some financial time-series plots. The user can choose between candlestick or OHLC plots to draw. To distinguish between 'up'/'down' movements different fill colours can be set for a candlestick plot, like so :

```
//have included only some part of the relevant initialisation code for brevity
CPTTradingRangePlot *candlestickPlot = [[CPTTradingRangePlot alloc] init];
[candlestickPlot setPlotStyle:CPTTradingRangePlotStyleCandleStick];
[candlestickPlot setIncreaseFill:[CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]]];
[candlestickPlot setDecreaseFill:[CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor redColor]]];

CPTTradingRangePlot *ohlcPlot = [[CPTTradingRangePlot alloc] init];
[ohlcPlot setPlotStyle:CPTTradingRangePlotStyleOHLC];
[ohlcPlot setIncreaseFill:[CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]]];
[ohlcPlot setDecreaseFill:[CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor redColor]]];
```

Can the colour of 'up'/'down' movements be changed for the OHLC plot? Currently, as shown in the code above, setting the increase/decrease fill does not have any affect on it.

If needed, I will be happy to share more code or information about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported in Core Plot right now. Please open an enhancement request on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues).

Comment: ok, thanks! I understand the direct functionality is not supported currently, but is there some workaround/alternate way to achieve a similar effect with OHLC plots? Like maybe changing the colour of individual sticks somehow?

Comment: You can use the `-lineStyleForTradingRangePlot:recordIndex:` datasource method to provide a different line style for each bar, but it is used to draw the whole bar, not just the high and low sticks.